# GroupJoin is throwing an error in Entity Framework. Join is working fine

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

```
var conversationQABySubjectId = 
    _repoWrapper.ConversationQuestionAnswer
                .FindAll()
                .Where(a => a.SubjectId == subjectId)
                .GroupJoin(_repoWrapper.ContactInformation.FindAll(),
                           c => c.ResponderContactInformationIdentifier,
                           ci => ci.ContactInformationIdentifier,
                           (c, ci) => new { c, ci })
                .Select(m => new Tuple<Domain.TC_Context.ConversationQuestionAnswer,
                                 Domain.TC_Context.ContactInformation>(m.c, m.ci));
```

`m.ci` is throwing this error shown below. This is working when I use Join.. I am using GroupJoin as I want to left join ContactInformation table.

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'TrainingCenter.Domain.TC_Context.ContactInformation'

Added `SelectMany` and `DefaultIfEmpty`, but none worked..below is the code

```
var conversationQABySubjectId = _repoWrapper.ConversationQuestionAnswer.FindAll()
                                    .Where(a => a.SubjectId == subjectId)
                                    .GroupJoin(_repoWrapper.ContactInformation.FindAll(),
                                    c => c.ResponderContactInformationIdentifier,
                                    ci => ci.ContactInformationIdentifier,
                                    (c, ci) => new { c, ci })
                                    .SelectMany(cci => cci.ci.DefaultIfEmpty(), (c, ci) => new { c, ci })
                                    .Select(m => new Tuple<Domain.TC_Context.ConversationQuestionAnswer,
                                                            Domain.TC_Context.ContactInformation>(m.c, m.ci));
```

Comment: .GroupJoin does not accomplish left outer join by itself. you still need the .DefaultIfEmpty().SelectMany() steps.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I added SelectMany and DefaultIfEmpty, but still getting same error. Any thoughts

Comment: because you've put .SelectMany() in the wrong place, m.ci is an IEnumerable, your Tuple expects a single ContactInformation.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I was able to fix it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I fixed the issue.

```
var conversationQABySubjectId = _repoWrapper.ConversationQuestionAnswer.FindAll()
                                        .Where(a => a.SubjectId == subjectId)
                                        .GroupJoin(_repoWrapper.ContactInformation.FindAll(),
                                        c => c.ResponderContactInformationIdentifier,
                                        ci => ci.ContactInformationIdentifier,
                                        (c, ci) => new { c, ci })
                                        .SelectMany(m => m.ci.DefaultIfEmpty(), (m,n) => new Tuple<Domain.TC_Context.ConversationQuestionAnswer,
                                                               Domain.TC_Context.ContactInformation>(m.c, n));
```